How do I use "concatenate" in a Keras model without getting shape related error?
I'm trying to create a U-Net architecture in Keras 2.15. The issue arises when I introduce the "concatenate" layers. The error seems to be related to the tensor shape being passed through the layers.
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-df6cb0d56434> in <cell line: 45>()
     43     return encoder, decoder, model
     44 
---> 45 encoder, decoder, model = build_unet(height, width, channels)
     46 
     47 print("Encoder input shape:", encoder.input_shape)

5 frames
<ipython-input-8-df6cb0d56434> in build_unet(height, width, channels, dropout_n, kernel_size)
     36 
     37     # Decoder model
---> 38     decoder = Model(decoder_input, outputs, name='decoder')
     39 
     40     # Full U-Net model

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203     try:
--> 204       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205     finally:
    206       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable, **kwargs)
    164                     inputs, outputs
    165                 )
--> 166         self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    167 
    168     @tf.__internal__.tracking.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203     try:
--> 204       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205     finally:
    206       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
    263 
    264         # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
--> 265         nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, _ = _map_graph_network(
    266             self.inputs, self.outputs
    267         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
   1143                 for x in tf.nest.flatten(node.keras_inputs):
   1144                     if id(x) not in computable_tensors:
-> 1145                         raise ValueError(
   1146                             "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for "
   1147                             f'tensor {x} at layer "{layer.name}". '

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 48, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input'), name='input', description="created by layer 'input'") at layer "conv_block". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

This is my architecture:
class ConvBlock(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, dropout_n, block_name, **kwargs):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.dropout_n = dropout_n
        self.block_name = block_name
        self.conv2d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same', name=f"conv2d_{block_name}")
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout_n, name=f"dropout_{block_name}")
        self.activation = Activation('relu', name=f"relu")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv2d(inputs)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x
    # etc


def encoder_block(inputs, filters, kernel_size, dropout_n, block_name):
    s = ConvBlock(filters, kernel_size, dropout_n, block_name)(inputs)
    p = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name=f"max_pooling_{block_name}")(s)
    return s, p

def decoder_block(inputs, skip_features, filters, kernel_size, dropout_n, block_name):
    d = UpSampling2D((2, 2), name=f"up_sampling_{block_name}")(inputs)
    d = Concatenate()([d, skip_features])
    d = ConvBlock(filters, kernel_size, dropout_n, block_name)(d)
    return d


def build_unet(height, width, channels, dropout_n=0.20, kernel_size=(3, 3)):
    # Encoder
    encoder_input = Input(shape=(height, width, channels), name='input')
    s1, p1 = encoder_block(encoder_input, 16, kernel_size, dropout_n, "1")
    s2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, 32, kernel_size, dropout_n, "2")
    s3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, 64, kernel_size, dropout_n, "3")
    s4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, 128, kernel_size, dropout_n, "4")

    b1 = ConvBlock(256, kernel_size, dropout_n, "5")(p4)
    
    # Encoder model
    encoder = Model(encoder_input, b1, name='encoder')

    latent_shape = encoder.output.shape[1:]

    # Decoder
    decoder_input = Input(shape=latent_shape, name='decoder_input')
    d1 = decoder_block(decoder_input, s4, 128, kernel_size, dropout_n, "6")
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 64, kernel_size, dropout_n, "7")
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 32, kernel_size, dropout_n, "8")
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 16, kernel_size, dropout_n, "9")

    outputs = Conv2D(channels, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', name='output')(d4)

    # Decoder model
    decoder = Model(decoder_input, outputs, name='decoder')

    # Full U-Net model
    model = Model(encoder_input, decoder(encoder(encoder_input)), name='unet')
    
    return encoder, decoder, model

encoder, decoder, model = build_unet(height, width, channels)

Originally I was working with TensorFlow v. 2.17.0 and Keras v. 3.4.1, I was receiving this error message when I tried to train the model:
KeyError: 'Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().\n\n\x1b[1m137598607979904\x1b[0m\n\nArguments received by Functional.call():\n  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 48, 64, 3), dtype=float32)\n  • training=True\n  • mask=None' 

That is why I switched to an older version of tensorflow, and since I am using Google Colab, I chose TensorFlow v. 2.15.0 and Keras v. 2.15.0 because that was the previous version Colab was using. I am still getting an error, but in a new place (progress?).

s4, s3, s2, s1, are not inputs to decoder, so you cannot supply them to the decoder_block function. You would have to add them all as input to the model.
